# How to fix SQL Server installing error?

Tags: sql-server, database, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008, but I am unable to install it. The error massage says:

> managed sql server installer has stopped working

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue:
Access the Programs and Features option.
Access the Turn Windows Features On or Off function.
Enable all options within the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 option.
Click OK to apply updates.
Once updated, attempt install.

Comment: Thanks . i will try now .